# Which trade route took the longest (in time) to travel?

Tags: trade

Which historic trade route took the longest in (time) to travel and how long did it take? Even better would be if somebody knew the commodities that were transported on the route.

Comment: I don't think a "trade route" is very a well defined unit.

Comment: Land route or sea route, or combined? Technically where did the silk road begin and end - Beijing and Dublin? Semaphore raises a very good point.

Comment: We could conjecture that on a long route such as the Silk Road most people in fact only traveled a length of it, then passed goods on to another merchant for the next segment.

Comment: Longest in Distance? In time? There was an ancient trade route from China to Western Europe, the "great silk way".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Manila Galleon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manila_galleon) might be a contender if you add the overland and transatlantic parts of the trip. Manila to Acapulco or Panama, Panama to Havana, Havana to Seville.

Do you count the round trip, if each leg waits for once-a-year seasonal winds?

Comment: No, I don't think I would count the round trip.